# IntellliJ VCS: ref mapping

Tags: git, intellij-idea, android-studio, gerrit

I'm using the [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) Version of IntelliJ-IDEA and would like to push my commits to *refs/for/** instead of *refs/heads/**.
But i can't find any settings for adjust the ref mappings. Any ideas?

[image: Intellij VCS GitPush]

Comment: [su] would be better suited for this question.

Comment: You're right - did't think about it since I've not posted anything there so far. Is there a way to 'move' this question?

Comment: There are two ways. 1). Easiest delete this question and ask it there. 2). Relatively time taking, flag it asking the moderator to migrate it to [su].

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Gerrit together with IntelliJ. You could use the intellij-gerrit-plugin. It also has Gerrit specific push support (refs/for target branch).

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7272